# Insert data into form field when pressing button on popup window

Tags: javascript, php, forms, popup

I'm building a simple PHP app that will hopefully allow a document path to be inserted into a form field from a popup.

In my form there is a button that will open a javascript popup box. This box loads a list of documents. I would like to have a link or button next to each document that when pressed in the popup window, inserts the file path into the parent page's form field.

Is this even possible? If so, I assume this has to be done through javascript. Unfortunately, I'm not very versed in JS and as such I'm having a hard time finding a solution.

Comment: What *kind* of popup?

Comment: `window.opener` will access the window that opened your popup window. You can set variables, call functions, etc.

Comment: I'm using onClick='javascript:popUp("")'

Comment: can you post some code what you have now ?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this (at least for me) is with jQuery:

Parent page html:

```
<a href='#' id='pop'>Popup</a>
<input id='path'></input>
<div id='popup'></div>
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script>
$('#pop').click(function(){
  $.get('load_form.php',function(data){
    $('#popup').html(data);
  });
});

$('#popup').on("click","a",function(){
  var path=$(this).href();
  $('#path').val(path);
  return false;
});
</script>
```

The child page that generates the popup should have anchor tags with href to the document you want to call.